# How to add non-ASCII String in OK-HTTP header?

Tags: java, android, base64, okhttp

I need to add a Base64 String in the header of my request.  And right now my base64 string is `mobileNum`+`pin` .  And this is how I generate the encoded String:

```
public static String getAuthentication(String userName,String spin)
{
    String userCredentials = userName+":"+spin;
    String base64=null;
    try
    {
        byte[] data = userCredentials.getBytes("UTF-8");
        base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){}

    String basicAuth = "Basic "+ new String(base64);

    return basicAuth;
}
```

And, now when I try to make a request from Ok-HTTP,

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url+sp.getString("MOB",""))
            .get()
            .addHeader("xkey", ""+Auth.getApiKey())
            .addHeader("authorization",""+Auth.getAuthentication(sp.getString("MOB",""),sp.getString("SPIN","")))
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();
```

it throws exception, saying :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x0a at 30 in authorization value: Basic OTE4MTExODExNjYwOjEyMzQ=

                  at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue(Headers.java:320)
                  at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:270)
                  at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:175)
                  at com.shreybank.shrey.activities.RegisterActivity.getCredentials(RegisterActivity.java:244)
                  at com.shreybank.shrey.activities.RegisterActivity.access$900(RegisterActivity.java:38)
                  at com.shreybank.shrey.activities.RegisterActivity$4.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:229)
                  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
                  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What is the best possible way to fix this?

Comment: can you edit my answer? i don't use the ok3http-lib and hence i get always stuck in typos - as you mentioned! best way would be that you edit my answer so other user can learn from you!

Answer (score 0):

`Basic OTE4MTExODExNjYwOjEyMzQ=`
`012345678901234567890123456789`

there is something attached to the end of your String!

`0xa = LF (Line Feed)`

you can see the line feed as a  in your stacktrace!

so you have an invalid line break at the end of your value. i cannot see any code where it will be added.  don't use `addHeader(...)` more than once, instead add the values to the header directly.

ok this it how to use it properly:

```
request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url+sp.getString("MOB",""))
        .get()
        .addHeader(
            new Headers.Builder().add("xkey", ""+Auth.getApiKey())
           .add("authorization",""+Auth.getAuthentication(sp.getString("MOB",""),sp.getString("SPIN","")))
           .add("cache-control", "no-cache")).build())
        .build();
```

ok, this code is **NOT** tested it merely explains how you should do it: use a new header builder, add the key/values and then create the header by calling `build()`

have a look at `HeaderBuilder`, see [HeaderBuilder](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Headers.Builder.html)!

Comment: yes, looks like you should not add more than one header! (use `Header.add(..)`  ) instead

Comment: Thanks for answering! But cannot resolve HeaderFactory()

Comment: thank you so much for clearing that out - i was working on a project and it was much about factorys so i was totally mind-absented...

Comment: uh man - it's really hard to write proper code when you're not using that library ^^